# Second C Linkage in shobjidl.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

I am currently moving a C++ project from VS6 to VS2008, but I have come accross the following error for many of the functions in shobjidl.h

```
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'HWND_UserMarshal' not allowed c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\shobjidl.h    28830
```

Not just HWND_UserMarshall is affected, also other functions in this header, such as HWND_UserSize, HWND_UserFree and HWND_UserFree64.

I understand that this error occurs when an extern "C" function is declared with a different set of parameters, however this is in a SDK header, not one that I can change.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what my next steps should be?

EDIT: The header is a Microsoft header and at the top contains the following comments

```
/* this ALWAYS GENERATED file contains the definitions for the interfaces */


 /* File created by MIDL compiler version 7.00.0499 */
/* Compiler settings for shobjidl.idl:
    Oicf, W1, Zp8, env=Win32 (32b run)
    protocol : dce , ms_ext, c_ext, robust
    error checks: allocation ref bounds_check enum stub_data 
    VC __declspec() decoration level: 
         __declspec(uuid()), __declspec(selectany), __declspec(novtable)
         DECLSPEC_UUID(), MIDL_INTERFACE()
*/
//@@MIDL_FILE_HEADING(  )
```

Comment: Like Max said there is probably a macro or #define somewhere that is causing problems.  Try figuring out where that header is being included and see if there's anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Are those headers generated from an IDL file? If so you probably need to re-generated them using a VS2008 compliant tool. 
For example if you are using the TAO ORB you would download the latest version (or the 2008 version) and run the tool:

```
tao_idl -Cw -GT shobjidl.idl
```

Using appropriate flags and paths.

**EDIT**: From your update it does seem like you are meant to generate this file. MIDL is the Microsoft IDL compiler. Check the docs on MSDN for info on the compiler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this header or these functions.  However, I suspect that there are C macros meant to control which functions are visible to you based on preprocessor defines.  And I suspect that you somehow have defined (or not defined) preprocessor symbols in a way that you're getting duplicate function definitions.

Not being familiar with the header, I can't really recommend what to do to get just the functions you want.  I would probably start by reading the documentation, looking at the configuration for similar products, and reading the header file itself.